# Boolean (setter-Getter) Cocos2D?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, boolean, getter-setter

I am making a game in Cocos2d.In my gameLayer I have a Boolean named bounce. When a collision between two bodies happens the value of bounce changes to true.

`bounce = true;`

how would i detect if the booleon is true or false in a character class ?

I'm thinking that i would have to use a (getter-setter) but I'm not sure how to set this up for a Boolean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can use a simple property, to create one in the interface add:

```
@property(nonatomic) BOOL bounce;
```

and in the class implementation add this right after @implementation:

```
@synthesize bounce=_bounce;
```

now you can access the BOOL variable in any other class that has reference to this class, e.g. in the character class:

```
if (theOtherClass.bounce) {
   //do stuff
}
```

There are of course other ways to tell your character class what to do, for example when you change the "bounce" variable to YES you could send your character class a method `[myCharacterClass myBounceMethod];`